# Music streaming site (Grooveshark) playlist, store locally or on server?

Tags: database, database-schema

I'm building a music streaming site much like grooveshark.com and I'm kind of lost on how to implement the playlist function.

The site is open to public, meaning you don't necessarily have to create an account to use the playlist function. So when a user starts building a playlist, where should I store it locally or on the server? Previously, I built it to store everything locally on a cookie but I don't think that's the correct way due to cookie limit(plus it was hacky).

So should I be creating a playlist on the server and interact with it every time user adds/drops/skips/pauses/etc music? What would the database structure look like? Create a GUID playlist anytime a visitor starts building a playlist, store the GUID locally on the user's computer cookie and use that to communicate with the server?